# Tunnelblick Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in tls-crypt (2.3.17)

Tags: mac-osx, openvpn

I have a new OpenVPN config which runs Ok on the server but the client fails to connect with the following error:

Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in /Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Users/Mark/markhorrocks.tblk/Contents/Resources/config.ovpn:28: tls-crypt (2.3.17)

Tunnelblick Log:

> *Tunnelblick: OS X 10.12.5; Tunnelblick 3.7.2beta03 (build 4840); prior version 3.7.2beta02 (build 4830) 2017-07-06 23:54:08
>   *Tunnelblick: Attempting connection with markhorrocks using shadow copy; Set nameserver = 771; monitoring connection 2017-07-06 23:54:08
>   *Tunnelblick: openvpnstart start markhorrocks.tblk 1337 771 0 1 0 1065264 -ptADGNWradsgnw 2.3.17-openssl-1.0.2k 2017-07-06 23:54:08
>   *Tunnelblick:
>
> Could not start OpenVPN (openvpnstart returned with status #251)
>
> Contents of the openvpnstart log:
>   *Tunnelblick: openvpnstart log:
>        Warning: Tunnelblick is using 'openvpn-down-root.so', so the route-pre-down script will not be used. You can override this by
>   providing a custom route-pre-down script (which may be a copy of
>   Tunnelblick's standard route-pre-down script) in a Tunnelblick VPN
>   Configuration. However, that script will not be executed as root
>   unless the 'user' and 'group' options are removed from the OpenVPN
>   configuration file. If the 'user' and 'group' options are removed,
>   then you don't need to use a custom route-pre-down script.OpenVPN
>   returned with status 1, errno = 0:
>             Undefined error: 0
>
> ```
>  Command used to start OpenVPN (one argument per displayed line):
>
>       /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/openvpn/openvpn-2.3.17-openssl-1.0.2k/openvpn
>       --daemon
>       --log
>       /Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Logs/-SUsers-SMark-SLibrary-SApplication
> ```
>
> Support-STunnelblick-SConfigurations-Smarkhorrocks.tblk-SContents-SResources-Sconfig.ovpn.771_0_1_0_1065264.1337.openvpn.log
>             --cd
>             /Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Users/Mark/markhorrocks.tblk/Contents/Resources
>             --verb
>             3
>             --config
>             /Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Users/Mark/markhorrocks.tblk/Contents/Resources/config.ovpn
>             --verb
>             3
>             --cd
>             /Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Users/Mark/markhorrocks.tblk/Contents/Resources
>             --management
>             127.0.0.1
>             1337
>             --management-query-passwords
>             --management-hold
>             --script-security
>             2
>             --up
>             /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/client.up.tunnelblick.sh
>   -9 -d -f -m -w -ptADGNWradsgnw
>             --plugin
>             /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/openvpn/openvpn-2.3.17-openssl-1.0.2k/openvpn-down-root.so
>             /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/client.down.tunnelblick.sh
>   -9 -d -f -m -w -ptADGNWradsgnw
>
> ```
>  Contents of the OpenVPN log:
>
>       Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in /Library/Application
> ```
>
> Support/Tunnelblick/Users/Mark/markhorrocks.tblk/Contents/Resources/config.ovpn:28:
>   tls-crypt (2.3.17)
>             Use --help for more information.
>
> ```
>  More details may be in the Console Log's "All Messages"
> ```
>
> ================================================================================

"Sanitized" full configuration file

```
client
proto udp
dev tun
remote vpn.mydomain.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-GCM
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-client
ping 15
ping-restart 120
route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
route-nopull

daemon

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
user nobody
group nogroup

<ca>
 [Security-related line(s) omitted]
</ca>
<cert>
 [Security-related line(s) omitted]
</cert>
<key>
 [Security-related line(s) omitted]
</key>
<tls-crypt>
 [Security-related line(s) omitted]
</tls-crypt>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OpenVPN added tls-crypt functionality in version 2.4+. Tunnelblick defaults to using OpenVPN 2.3.7 in the settings for some reason, even in the latest releases (from what I have experienced). So just update the 'OpenVPN' version in the 'Settings' menu of Tunnelblick to 2.4+ and you should be good to go!

Comment: The sad there is that supporting multiple computer illiterate clients is difficult. It would be nice if they defaulted to the latest version.